# Проблема с background-attachment

Tags: html, css

Возникла проблема с расположением фиксированного фона.

**html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head><head>
    <body>
        <div class="background"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**css:**

```
html, body{height: 100%}
body{margin-right: 300px;}
.background{height: 100%; background: url('http://oi67.tinypic.com/2guecyo.jpg') center top fixed;}
```

**jsfiddle:**
https://jsfiddle.net/84av76hh/

**текущее поведение:**

Фиксированный фон элемента **.background** игнорирует заданное ему горизонтальное выравнивание и позиционируется относительно общей ширины документа.

**желаемое поведение:**

Хотелось бы, чтобы фиксированный фон был центрирован относительно ширины элемента, к которому применен, а не к общей ширине.

Как быть?

Comment: А что значит центрован? Может здесь дело именно в размере блока в котором находится этот фон? Если например сделать background-size: 50% то можно увидеть, что он центрируется относительно всего элемента. https://jsfiddle.net/84av76hh/2/

Answer (score 1):

долго вникал в суть проблемы, потом наконец понял.

```
.background{height: 100%; 
background: url('http://oi67.tinypic.com/2guecyo.jpg') center top fixed;
background-position: top right 35%;
}
```

частично решается проблема, но все равно не то. а без "fixed" получается так, как нужно. довольно странно. еще можно попробовать загнать в div, который будет использоваться только для фона.